# Form submission is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a form which I would like to submit using jQuery if the result of `checkBrowser` function is `old`.

```
<form action="xxx" method="post">
...
<input id="iop" type="submit">
...
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#iop").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var status=checkBrowser();
    if(status=='old'){
        $("#iop").submit();
    }
});
```

What I have done:

I debugged the code and it reaches the line `$("#iop").submit();` but nothing happens. any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `submit()` on `<form>` not `<input>` element. From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)**:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements

```
if(status=='old'){
    $("form").submit();
}
```

or more specific by using **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the closest matching `form` element of your submit button when traverse up the DOM tree:

```
if(status=='old'){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you are refering to the `submit input` instead of the `form`.

**Change this:**

```
  $("#iop").submit();
```

**To this:**

```
  $("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `submit()` explicitly, let the default action do it:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    var status=checkBrowser();
    if(status != 'old'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Also, bind the handler to the form's `submit` event, not the button.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be used at the beginning

Comment: Not if you want it to be conditional on `status`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<input id="iop" type="submit">`  to `<input id="iop" type="button">`

and `$("#iop").submit();` to `$("form").submit();`

Try this

```
<form action="xxx" method="post">
<input id="iop" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#iop").mousedown(function(e){

    //e.preventDefault();
   // var status=checkBrowser();
   status = "old";

    if(status=='old'){
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
    });
</script>
```